# Excel forumla for converting text to date, day & time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have column filled with below text data

```
Sun Aug 30 23:49:00 IST 2015
```

I need to split in three columns:

1. Time "23:49:00"
2. Date  "Aug 30 2015" and
3. Day "Sun".

Comment: If it's just a one-time, you can convert data via "text to columns" functionality. Otherwise, you can [split the string across columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8). Either way, you should not need VBA.

Comment: @LaurIvan That should just be the answer, I was going to say the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without macro, but if macros are needed as part of a larger effort, then:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim v As String, r As Range
   For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      v = r.Value
      If v <> "" Then
         ary = Split(v, " ")
         r.Offset(0, 1) = ary(3)
         r.Offset(0, 2) = ary(1) & " " & ary(2) & " " & ary(5)
         r.Offset(0, 3) = ary(0)
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

The code can be adapted to handle your choice of columns.

Comment: You could use `" " & ary(5)` rather than the hardcoded `" 2015"` to handle different years.

Answer (score 0):

If the date you're attempting to read is in cell A1, then the following three formulas will work:

### Day

```
=LEFT(A1, 3)
```

### Date

```
=TRIM(MID(A1, 5, 6)) & RIGHT(A1, 5)
```

### Time

```
=TRIM(MID(A1, 11, 9))
```